# How to search specific word/s from string by ignoring a particular character using re python

Tags: python, regex

There is a string in which I want search for a specific words using regular expression. But the scenario is I am getting white space character within the word. So according to below example I want search for all *Oklahoma* and *Kansas* but there is space in both the words. It is not certain that where and how many space would appear in search word, it could be anywhere.

Is there any way that I can search for a word or name ignoring any space within ?

My string:

```
Texas           West           South         M i rando    North  Okl ahoma
N.W.           K ansas           LLS\r\n    K an sas                                           
Panhandle        Texas           Texas         Oklaho ma            Texas         
Panhandle      Oklahoma    Kan sas
```

Required output:

```
Oklahoma
Kansas
Kansas
Oklahoma
Oklahoma
Kansas
```

Comment: Is it one string? Looks like more of a table structure. Does it have a structure? If so, can use `csv` reader of other simpler tools than `regex`...

Comment: No @Aaron_ab its a part of string from text document.

Comment: Seems the answer you need is @Alex Hall's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

string = '''Texas           West           South         M i rando    North  Okl ahoma
N.W.           K ansas           LLS\r\n    K an sas                                           
Panhandle        Texas           Texas         Oklaho ma            Texas         
Panhandle      Oklahoma    Kan sas'''

words = ['Kansas', 'Oklahoma']
pattern = '|'.join(r'\s*'.join(word) for word in words)
print(pattern)
print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

Output:

```
K\s*a\s*n\s*s\s*a\s*s|O\s*k\s*l\s*a\s*h\s*o\s*m\s*a
['Okl ahoma', 'K ansas', 'K an sas', 'Oklaho ma', 'Oklahoma', 'Kan sas']
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex_Hall for your answer. Is there any way that we can do it for all the required words at once ?

Comment: @Shadkhan like this?